# Inequality with $W^{1,p}$ norm

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

For $a<b \in \mathbb{R}$, let $G = (a,b)$. How can I show that firstly for every $v \in W^{1,p}(G)$ there exists a unique $\tilde{v} \in C^0(\overline{G})$ such that for almost every $x \in G$ it holds that $v(x) = \tilde{v}(x)$? And secondly that for every $p \in [1,\infty]$ there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $$ \lVert \tilde{v} \rVert_{C^0(\overline{G})} \leq C \lVert v \rVert_{W^{1,p}(G)}$$
for every $v \in W^{1,p}(G)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both claims hold since $W^{1,p}(G)\hookrightarrow C^0(\overline{G}).$
Just look for Sobolev embeddings and note that $\text{dim}G=1$.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit (I don't have too much of a math background)? And what is a Sobolev embedding?

Comment: You can google "Morrey Inequality" (or search in "Partial Differential Equations" of Evans) and read a bit about this topic. For $\gamma=0$ (usually it's $\gamma$ but you will see) it's exactly your Problem.